# Scrolling Programmatically THorzScrollBox Firemonkey XE6

Tags: delphi, scroll, firemonkey, delphi-xe6, tscrollbox

I have a `THorzScrollBox` in a form, and some `TStyledControls` inside. Each `StyledControl` has a `Tag` to identify. Using an `TEdit` to inform a value, I can find inside the `ScrollBox` an specific `Control` by his `tag`.

If the `control` that I searched is not on the screen, I want to scroll the `ScrollBox` to show it.

How can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a way to do this.
I have to use `ScrollBy`. But the detail is that if I want to scroll the controls to right I have to use a negative value.
Example:

```
sbItems.ScrollBy(-10, 0); // this will scroll to right
```

If I use a positive value, it will scroll to left.

```
sbItems.ScrollBy(10, 0); // this will scroll to left
```

The point is, if you scroll once, the `ViewportPosition` will change and the next time you execute `ScrollBy`, it will not reset the scroll position, it will scroll from the point you already have scrolled.