# Reposition image in TImageViewer

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

i'm building an FMX app for iOS, it has a `TImageViewer` on a `TPanel` with the `TImageViewer`aligned to Contents. I load a bitmap from file into the `TImageViewer` and i can then pan around and zoom in/out on the image.  Works fine.

What i want now is a button click event to **reposition** the left edge of the image on the left edge of the `TPanel` so it looks like the top image below.

Here is example of what it looks like when first loaded:

[image]

Here it is after i have panned it around:

[image]

I've searched and experimented all day but i just can't get it.  I tried reloading the bitmap file but did nothing.  Any suggestions?

thanks, russ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way based on [this delphi question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681719/scrolling-programmatically-thorzscrollbox-firemonkey-xe6).  Note that ImageMap is the name of my  `TImageViewer` on Form1.

```
TPointF myOffset;
myOffset = Form1->ImageMap->ViewportPosition; // this is (0,0) before the image is panned around, non-zero otherwise
Form1->ImageMap->ScrollBy(myOffset.X, myOffset.Y) ;
```